# What is the purpose for the art-style of puck changing by scene?

Tags: berserk

In some chapters or even as cover art in berserk puck is drawn fully with detail as shown here:
[image]
[image]
[image]

But in several chapters he is drawn like this:

[image]

[image]

Is there a reason for neglecting detail? I noticed that when he comes in as comic relief he seems to miss alot of detail like so. But is there some sort of artistic reason behind this choice that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for comic relief purposes only. The technique is known as **Deanimation/Cut-Out**. Check more details below.

> http://www.japanpowered.com/anime-articles/anime-facial-expressions

Here read the part about Deanimation cut out. Another one of the Top Manga (and Anime) which uses this is Full Metal Alchemist. The purpose is the same for i.e. Comic relief especially with the Elric Brothers.

[image: FMA: Elric Brothers Cutout]

Saying this is neglecting detail is kinda offensive to me cause the attention to details, the beautiful and horrifying art work is one of the main reasons many people still read Berserk even though it is a disappointment that the progress has been so slow.

Also google "Puck's Funny Expressions". I know it can be jarring but lots of people (me included) find the little humour in the dark and gruesome world refreshing.

[image: Lol]