# What is this expresison/anime trope called?

Tags: tropes

[image]

Say, character2 says or does something -- usually stupid in nature -- in which character1 responds with a similar face and a comment of their own. I see this a lot in anime, and I was wondering if it had a name. This happens a lot in Naruto.

Comment: I don't think it's a "trope" when people reply to what other people say and have a distinct facial expression. It's just normal interaction.

Comment: Probably related. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/33679/what-is-the-purpose-for-the-art-style-of-puck-changing-by-scene The bland face is used for comic relief

Answer (score 1):

Is a visual cue to establish who is the "straight man" in the comedy bit.
Funny man: I Really like ceilings, I guess I am a ceiling fan!
Straight man: ¬_¬

Answer (score 1):

I don't know regarding the facial expressions, but your description of their dialogue seems to be a typical example of *boke* (character 2) and *tsukkomi* (character 1) in [manzai comedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manzai). This type of humour is typically japanese and can be seen or heard in most variety shows and anime with humoristic tendancies.
Anime also tend to have the variation of "*boke* and *boke*", where both characters say stupid things.